# How \ can move run window to external display in PhpStorm 2017.2 in mac os?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, windowed

How \ can move run or debug window to external display in PhpStorm 2017.2 in mac os?

I can move only window with source one file, or terminal tab.

But i don't know how move debug and run window to External Display.

Maybe exist some issue in JetBrains Tracker?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on a "gear" icon and select Floating mode. After that debug/run tool window will be detached & you'll be able to move it around.

[image: eh]